# Firebase in chrome extension Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I try to migrate my chrome-extension from manifest version 2 to v3, and was wondering if it is possible to use FCM in chrome extension Manifest version 3.

As I could not find helpful documentation/guides on this topic, I hope this thread will also be helpful to others.

In manifest version 2 I use the following code:

**firebase-messaging-sw.js:**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "<api-key>",
     authDomain: "<auth-domain>",
     projectId: "<project-id>",
     storageBucket: "<storage-bucket>",
     messagingSenderId: "<messaging-sender-id>",
     appId: "<app-id>",
};

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging();

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, async (payload) => {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

    const allClients = await self.clients.matchAll({ includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'all' })

    allClients.forEach((client: any) => {
        client.postMessage({ type: 'msg_type', payload });
    });
});
```

**In the background.js (now my SW):**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "<api-key>",
        authDomain: "<auth-domain>",
        projectId: "<project-id>",
        storageBucket: "<storage-bucket>",
        messagingSenderId: "<messaging-sender-id>",
        appId: "<app-id>",
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging and get a reference to the service
    const messaging = getMessaging(app);

    getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "<vapid-key>" })
        .then((registrationToken: string) => {

            onMessage(messaging, async (payload) => {
                //doSomething
            });

        });

    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', async (message: MessageEvent) => {
        if (message.data.type === 'msg_type') {
            //doSomething
        }
    });

}
```

I try to follow [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6137) guide, and other related threads/videos,
But there is no guide for firebase-messaging-sw.js or other alternatives that I have found.

Hope you can help with this.